# Child component not re rendering after Parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I have a `RadioGroup` component that contains multiple `RadioButton` components. Here's the code for the `RadioGroup` component:

```
const RadioGroup = ({radioGroupData}) => {
    const [radioGroupRefreshData, setRadioGroupRefreshData] = useState(radioGroupData);

    const handleClick = (index) => {
        setRadioGroupRefreshData(radioGroupRefreshData.map((obj, i) => {
            if(i !== index) {
                return {text: obj.text, isSelected: false};
            }
            return {text: obj.text, isSelected: true};
        }));
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {
                radioGroupRefreshData.map((obj, i) => {
                    return <RadioButton index={i}
                                        text={obj.text}
                                        isSelected={obj.isSelected}
                                        onClick={handleClick} />
                })
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

The `RadioGroup` component has a state variable (an array) called `radioGroupRefreshData`. when each RadioButton is defined inside the RadioGroup, the `handleClick` function is passed as a prop in order to be called when a RadioButton is clicked. Here is the code for the `RadioButton` component:

```
const RadioButton = (props) => {
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(props.isSelected);

    const initialRenderDone = useRef(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!initialRenderDone.current) {
            initialRenderDone.current = true;
        }
        else {
            props.onClick(props.index);
        }
    }, [isSelected]);

    const handlePress = () => {
        if(!isSelected) {
            setIsSelected(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.outsideContainer} onPress={handlePress}>
            <View style={styles.radioButtonContainer}>
                { (isSelected) && <RadioButtonInnerIcon width={15} height={15} fill="#04004C" /> }
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.radioButtonText}>{props.text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

From what I know, each RadioButton component should re render when the Parent's variable `radioGroupRefreshData` changes, but the RadioButton component's are not re rendering.

Thank you in advance for any help that you can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a state in RadioButton you need to update it when the props change. So in RadioButton add useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsSelected(props.isSelected);
},[props.isSelected]);
```

Also you don't have to mix controlled and uncontrolled behaviour of the component: do not set RadioButton state inside RadioButton since it comes from the RadioGroup

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you so much!

Comment: So basically the reason why the child was not re rendering was because it state depends on the value of some state variable that is defined on the parent? Right?

Comment: No, because the external state from parent was used only once - during the initialization.